# Jenkins Blue Ocean new pipeline doesn't save to Github

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a local Jenkins Docker image running and I'm trying to create a pipeline with Blue Ocean. I gave Jenkins a Github access token with the correct permissions to my repo but when I try and save the pipeline, Blue Ocean just sits there and nothing happens even though it says it's saving a new `Jenskinsfile` to my repo. I don't see any changes in my repo.

[image: Jenkins Blue Ocean - saving pipeline]

Answer (score 0):

Started to work after I updated the pipeline to only have 1 stage (instead of 3). Not sure if this is a bug.